# "The visual basic for applications (vba) macros in this workbook are corrupted and have been deleted"

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, vba

Recently, I found an Excel 2007 Macro Enable Spreadsheet are keep getting the following error message:

> The visual basic for applications (VBA) macros for this workbook are
>   corrupted and has been deleted. The macros corruption most likely
>   exists in the current file. To recover the macros, open up a backup
>   copy of this file if you have one.

But they can run it before. Besides, a few of guys can run this excel spreadsheet well. 
The OS of these laptops are almost the same since we install them via the SCCM including the office 2007 .

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 2):

This error is typically caused when VBA was not included in the original Office installation.

You should be able to modify the Office installation via `Control Panel > Add and Remove Programs` and choose `Change`. *The exact process may be different depending on the OS.*

[Source](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/822897-excel-corrupt-macro-message.html)